# Adding Imports and Customizing Echarts/other Plugin Code in Grafana

Tags: javascript, typescript, grafana, echarts, webmin

I'm encountering issues with customizing plugins like Echarts/HTML graphics within Grafana. Specifically, I'm struggling to locate where the code for these plugins is located within Grafana. Ideally, I want to customize existing code by modifying parameters or adding additional imports.

When downloading Echarts independently, I have access to the entire package and can freely browse through its files. However, after downloading it as a plugin for Grafana, I'm unable to locate these files.

Additional Information:

- I access Grafana through my PC.
- The physical location of Grafana can be accessed through Webmin.

Any insights into where Grafana stores plugin files or how I can access and customize them would be greatly appreciated

[echarts directories from git example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyVLC.png)

[echarts plugin directories in webmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhbt8.png)

---

- I've tried making the plugin use global imports like html2pdf which was installed with npm.
- Tried adding import to module.ts in plugin folder but it bricked all my echart graphs.
- Tried making custom script with node but also couldn't access it with echarts.
- Tried using HtmlGraphics plugin, but also wasn't able to use libraries like html2pdf, jspdf etc.

Ideally I want to be able to add imports so that echarts or other plugins could use them.